# Nuxt 3 - how to hide a div on a specific page

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm sure this question may seem ridiculous to some. I'm a beginner in web programming and I'm only starting to learn how to use Nuxt3.
I have a banner on my navbar and I would like for it to be present on all the pages except for the homepage but I don't know how to begin.
Do I use route in any way, something like if (route === "homepage"), do X ?
I have only seen the basics of the basics for now so I'm a bit lost.

Thank you all in advance !

Answer (score 2):

For your case, you can easily use Nuxt Layout. Create a layout folder in your project root dir. Then create two layouts like this

- /layout/home.ts
- /layout/default.ts

Then go to your pages component and use which layout you want for each page using the `definePageMeta` like this

```
<script setup>
  definePageMeta({
    layout: 'home'
  })
</script>
```

And put your layout-specific design in the layout.

Comment: So simple and effective !
Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You can set the condition using `route.name`. Nuxt provides route automatically according to folder structure therefore once you console the `route` on your page you can see the current page properties like name, path, etc...

Please check below demo code

```js
<template>
 <div v-if="route.name == 'index'"> YOUR BANNER DIV </div>
<template>

<script setup>
const route = useRoute();
</script>
```